# Portaudio Error on Ubuntu and Raspbian

Tags: c, linux, alsa, portaudio

I recently started to use PortAudio in a C program, but I've got trouble initializing it. The problem lies in the **Pa_Initialize()** function.

Here's my code:

```
#include "portaudio.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {

    PaError err;

    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if ( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    error:
        Pa_Terminate();
        fprintf( stderr, "******* ERROR *******\n" );
        fprintf( stderr, "Error number: %d\n", err );
        fprintf( stderr, "Error message: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText( err ) );
        return err;

}
```

I received the following error:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
******* ERROR *******
Error number: 0
Error message: Success
```

The code was tried on **Linux Mint 17.2** and **Ubuntu 14.04**. The only difference is that on Ubuntu, the line at the end,

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
```

doesn't show up.

EDIT 2: The first two lines don't show up in Ubuntu either.

I also tried eliminating the handling of errors, leaving only **Pa_Initialize();** in the main function. As expected, only the last three lines of the error message disappeared.

I did some research on the web, but couldn't find someone with the same problem.

The [PortAudio documentation](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h.html#abed859482d156622d9332dff9b2d89da) didn't help either.

EDIT 1: Earlier, I tried using PyAudio in Python. Although it uses PortAudio, the initialization worked there.

EDIT 3: The following code gives me a "segmentation fault" message:

Code:

```
#include "portaudio.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {

    PaStreamParameters *inputParameters;

    PaError err;
    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if ( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    (*inputParameters).device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice();

    error:
        Pa_Terminate();
        fprintf( stderr, "******* ERROR *******\n" );
        fprintf( stderr, "Error number: %d\n", err );
        fprintf( stderr, "Error message: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText( err ) );
        return err;

}
```

Message (last line is new):

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Segmentation fault
```

EDIT 4: On Raspberry Pi 2B, I get the following message when executing the first code:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
******* ERROR *******
Error number: 0
Error message: Success
```

Comment: This is a problem with your computer, not your code

Comment: This is a problem with PortAudio; it tries to find all kinds of devices (most of which don't exist on your computer), and outputs messages even when failures can be expected.

Comment: @CL. My computer does have an integrated microphone and speaker. And the initialization did work with PyAudio. Is there a way to help PortAudio find the devices?

Comment: Why? doesn't it find your devices?

Comment: @CL. Trying to set a default device with the line "inputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice();" (inputParameters being of the type PaStreamParameters) gives a segmentation fault

Comment: There is no such line in the code you've shown in the question.

Comment: Maybe an extra command is needed which PyAudio generates automatically.

Comment: @CL. I added it once to test it out, in case it would work anyway.

Comment: The seg fault in your second bit of code is because you create a pointer with `PaStreamParameters *inputParameters;`, and then try to access it before youve allocated any memory. Either create the inputParameters statically (i.e. without the asterisk), or malloc() some memory for it. Try fixing that then update.

Comment: @timofiend Thank you so much, again!!! The memory allocation resolved the issue.

Comment: Heh no problem, glad you got it working!